# MonoTouch - get list of connected outlets

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, viewdidunload

I am working on a large iOS application and am at the phase where I'm doing some cleanup/performance tuning.

One of the things I need to do is override `ViewDidUnload` everywhere and take the appropriate action, and the most common thing that needs to be done is to set all outlets within the `UIViewController` to `null`.  Is there a way through MonoTouch APIs to get a list of connected outlets in a `UIViewController`?  This will make this process much more robust, as I won't have to do anything if I add new outlets.

NOTE: I know setting all outlets to null won't catch every referenced view, but should get a large portion.

Comment: Reflection is the first thing that comes to mind. However, I do not think this is what you are looking for...

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping MonoTouch had them cached where reflection wouldn't  be required.  Although it might be a decent option (I will maybe try a quick speed test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Xamarin has been at work to fix this in the latest version of MonoTouch/MonoDevelop .

There is a designer-generated `ReleaseDesignerOutlets()` that you can call in `ViewDidUnload`.  You can view the method in any *.designer.cs file.

Not sure if there is a good way to fix existing views created prior to the latest MonoDevelop, however.

Comment: If you reopen all your xibs in Xcode and then just add a blank line in each of the header files generated for use with drag&dropping outlets/actions, MonoDevelop will re-parse those header files and regenerate the .designer.cs file, adding the ReleaseDesignerOutlets() method implementation.